# How do I get an AngularJS http post to a PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to decipher how to get the json post from a JavaScript file to a PHP file.

This is my JS file:

```
var url2 = '/php/extractkeywords.php';
var jsonData = angular.toJson({
text: $scope.userTyping,
data: post
});

$http({
   url: url2,
   method: "POST",
   data: "data=" + window.btoa($scope.textHTML),
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      // Sending to extractkeywords.php
})
```

And this is my PHP file:

```
$data = json_decode(urldecode(base64_decode($_POST["data"])));
```

When I try to print $data, I don't get anything.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with angular, but you can use json_last_error to see what went wrong with the json_decode. It also will be helpful in debugging this to separate all of the various decodes into separate statements and var_dump in between so you can see what's happening.

Comment: It works in another file, but not in this one.

Comment: I would start from looking into dumping $_POST["data"] than base64_decode($_POST["data"]) than urldecode(base64_decode($_POST["data"])) just to see what you have there might be not a json

Comment: What if it keeps saying NULL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass JSON, here:

```
data: "data=" + window.btoa($scope.textHTML),
```

you are using the equals sign, which should not be used. JSON can have objects, arrays and key-value pairs, so you need a key. I believe this would improve your code:

```
data: {data: window.btoa($scope.textHTML)},
```

Comment: tried that but didn't work. Didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @azmatrix, this is part of the solution, to make sure you send the data well. The other part is to receive it well. After you do this, you can var_dump $_POST

Comment: The file contains similar code to other parts of files. They work, it is only my understanding of how to receive that doesn't. I've tested this...